# Unit of measurement for Duration column in SQL Profiler

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

What is the unit of the Duration column in SQL Profiler? I thought it was milliseconds but in the following Profiler row I found it contradicting with start and end time:

```
spid=163    
duration=11310646
starttime=2010-04-06 17:45:24.480
endtime=2010-04-06 17:45:35.790
reads=152
writes=2
cpu=16
eventclass=12
textdata= DELETE FROM dbo.[Icon] WHERE Id = 20087
```

FYI, I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: The question [SQL Profiler CPU / duration units](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976628/) gives a detailed answer

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175848.aspx). It says

> In SQL Server
>   2005 and later, the SQL Server
>   Profiler graphical user interface
>   displays the Duration column in
>   milliseconds by default, but when a
>   trace is saved to either a file or a
>   database table, the Duration column
>   value is written in microseconds

I was watching them after saving the trace file in database.

Comment: This answer was for version 2008 may be now it has been changed. May be now there is some config which may change this behavior.