# sp duration does not equal the sum of statement duration in sql profiler

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-profiler

I have a sp which takes over 6000 ms in sql profiler, but when I looked at the statement execution duration in this sp, most of them are 0, the sum of statement execution time is far less than 6000, i have no idea where the 6000ms come from... Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Profiler the duration numbers are in microseconds not milliseconds.

You're probably seeing your statement results rounded down to 0s from 0.000001s.

[SQL Profiler CPU / duration units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976628)