# What "duration" is SQL Profiler's "duration" measuring?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

I'm having strange timeout errors on a server for trivial queries (that take too long even when no other server load is going on).

Using **Extended Events** or **SQL Profiler**, I monitored a query:

- **Timestamp**: 12/7/2017 12:14:36 PM
- **Name**: sql_batch_completed
- **Batch Text**: `SELECT 'Testing Connection...'`
- **Result**: OK
- **Row Count**: 1
- **Logical Reads**: 0
- **CPU Time**:  78,000 us (78 ms)
- **Duration**:  15,796,907 us (***15,797 ms***)

For some reason the query:

> SELECT 'Testing Connection...'

took **15 seconds** to complete.

But what took 15 seconds to complete? It only took 78ms of CPU time. What was in the other 14.2 seconds?

What is the **duration** that SQL Profiler (and Extended Events) are measuring?

Is it Time-To-Last-Byte delivered to the client? If so, how does it know when the last byte was delivered to the client?

If it does include network time, then this is a fairly slow LAN sometimes.

### Books Online

From the SQL Server 2000 Books Online (the last time Profiler was documented):

> ### SQL Profiler Data Columns
>
> SQL Profiler allows you to select data columns when you create a template. These data columns represent the information you would like returned when a trace is running. The data displayed in SQL Profiler can be displayed either in the order the events occur or in a group based on one or a combination of data columns.
>
> The following table describes the SQL Profiler data columns, and which are selected by default.
>
> ```
> | Data Column | Column Number | Description                                           |
> |-------------|---------------|-------------------------------------------------------|
> | Duration    | 13            | Amount of time (in milliseconds) taken by the event.  |
> ```

### Bonus Reading

- [SQL Profiler CPU / duration units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976628/sql-profiler-cpu-duration-units)
- [Unit of measurement for Duration column in SQL Profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590304/unit-of-measurement-for-duration-column-in-sql-profiler)
- [Duration unit in SQL Server trace file](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165912/duration-unit-in-sql-server-trace-file)

Comment: Can you compare the values of that query with the client stats in SSMS?

Comment: @Pred It's an intermittent issue; every time i run the same query from another machine on the LAN (or even remotely over the internet), it is nearly instant (<1s)

Comment: Can you please check if the display unit is set to microseconds in the profiler (Tools > Options -> General -> A checkbox saying show duration in microseconds.) Using extended events, the duration should be in microseconds instead of milliseconds.

Comment: @Pred *Extended Events* show values in microseconds (us). For convenience i also show the equivalent milliseconds.